# How to get random key from firebase realtime database in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

When i push to create a random generated entry i want to save the randomly generated value as a field inside of itself.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());


    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Guest").push();


    getLocationUpdates();
    readChanges();
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

[image: Firebase screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Calling `push()` generates a new `DatabaseReference` with a unique key. You can get that key with:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Guest").push();
String key = reference.getKey();
```

So you can then write that value into the database where you need it.